# Which part of the valve stem do i need to replace?

Tags: tires, valve

I cant tell which part is messed up (I hit it with a hammer accidentally while trying to get my tire off). Do I need to replace the whole system, or just the body?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to have the whole thing replaced. That appears to be a stem for a tire pressure sensor. In order to fix this, you'll have to have the tire broke down, then pull the sensor off the rim. Then disassemble the sensor and place the guts into a new shell. You could just put in a new sensor, but you'd then have to have it programmed into the tire monitor system.

Comment: What do you mean when you say I need to have the tire broke down? Do you mean take it off the rim? I was going to do that at home but that seems challenging to do if I cant deflate the tire because the valve is busted :(

Comment: @ale19 - Yes, you have to pull the bead of the tire away from the rim on at least the side where the valve stem is at ... this is because in order to do any work to the valve stem, you have to access it from the interior part. There is no way to do what you need to do from the exterior.